# Annotation as shortcut for another annotation?

Tags: java, annotations, jackson

How can I create an annotation, such as @DateOutput that is equivalent with another Jackson annotation, such as:

```
@JsonFormat(shape=JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern="yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ", timezone="UTC")
```

Or ideally, to a set of annotations, such as

```
@JsonSerialize(using = XSerializer.class)
@JsonDeserialize(using = XDeserializer.class)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `@JacksonAnnotationsInside` as a annotation container like follows:

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({ElementType.FIELD, ElementType.METHOD})
@JacksonAnnotationsInside
@JsonFormat(shape=JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern="yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ", timezone="UTC")
public @interface DateOutput {
}
```

and use it to annotate the field in your class like so:

```
public class Foo {

   @DateOutput
   private Date date;

}
```

You can also bundle a set of annotations under a single annotation:

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({ElementType.FIELD, ElementType.METHOD})
@JacksonAnnotationsInside
@JsonSerialize(using = XSerializer.class)
@JsonDeserialize(using = XDeserializer.class)
public @interface MyAnnotation {
}
```

Comment: Thanks! That's exactly what I was looking for!