# Use annotation in other annotation

Tags: java, annotations

There are some modules that contain methods which are marked with the following annotation:

```
@SuppressWarnings({"WeakerAccess"})
```

When this annotation is added,
the compiler does not give warning about the access modifier can be more private.
Some of the time this is done because some child class (outside the module) will override the method.
When this is the case,
we are required to add a comment stating that the method be overridden.
Now,
for every method and variable,
we have two things,
the annotation and the comment.

Does Java let us create an annotation which can indicate both cases.
This is what I have:

```
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;

import static java.lang.annotation.ElementType.CONSTRUCTOR;
import static java.lang.annotation.ElementType.FIELD;
import static java.lang.annotation.ElementType.LOCAL_VARIABLE;
import static java.lang.annotation.ElementType.METHOD;
import static java.lang.annotation.ElementType.PARAMETER;
import static java.lang.annotation.ElementType.TYPE;

@Target({TYPE, FIELD, METHOD, PARAMETER, CONSTRUCTOR, LOCAL_VARIABLE})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.SOURCE)
@SuppressWarnings({"WeakerAccess"})
public @interface WillBeOverriden { } // Ignore the ugly name
```

The goal of this new annotation is that it will behave exactly the same as the SuppressWarnings annotation and removes the need to add a java comment; since the annotation will act as the comment.

[This stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38643475/annotation-as-shortcut-for-another-annotation) seems to have the answer,
but my compiler still complains that the field can be more private.

Comment: Such a meta-annotation feature is not part of core Java. Some frameworks support this (for example, Spring) but it depends on whatever processes the annotations, and the Java compiler itself, which looks at for example `@SuppressWarnings`, does not support this.

Comment: "WeakerAccess" is a warning by IntelliJ, right? I would assume the IDE has some feature to restrict this warning to certain packages/projects so that you don't have to suppress it manually in classes that are public API